# Change background of windows 10 using python

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering that can we change windows 10 background using python i did a bit research and find a module name ctypes but the problem was that it needs a image to apply but i want that instead of a locally saved file it should use a url of a image and refresh the background at a interval with a new image. Cuz i want to create a script which will apply an anime wallpaper in every 5 minute and the url will be taken from a api.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows with python2.5 or higher, use ctypes to load user32.dll and call SystemParametersInfo() with SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER action.

For example:

```
import ctypes
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "image.jpg" , 0)
```

Comment: uhh this code works but i have multiple images and i want that image will change on a time interval for example i have 10 images and i want that in every 2 minutes the wallpaper change from those 10 images

Answer (score 0):

Your script will have to do that in two steps

1. Download the image from the url using a package like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)
2. Set the Windows Background